# Does email required for Firebase auth with Google Sign in?

Tags: android, firebase, google-oauth, firebase-authentication

I've started migrating my project to Firebase. Previously I used auth without email, because user might want not to show it. But in firebase samples I see

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

Does it really required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just specify that you want to read user's **email**, If you don't want it , You  don't need to call  `requestEmail()` .